# Package babel error

Tags: packages, babel

I try to compile my french report, but I get these two errors :

> - Package babel error : language definition file Frenchb.ldf not found \ProcessOptions*
> - Package babel error : you haven't specified a language option try to proceed from here, type x to quit}

Here is the latex code of babel.sty

```
\ProcessOptions*
\ifx\bbl@main@language\@undefined
  \PackageError{babel}{%
    You haven't specified a language option}{%
    You need to specify a language, either as a global
    option\MessageBreak
    or as an optional argument to the \string\usepackage\space
    command; \MessageBreak
    You shouldn't try to proceed from here, type x to quit.}
  \input{babel.def}
\fi
```

I try to update texlive, but I get always the same problem

> sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-all

Here the code.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,onehalfspacing,headrules,tools]{report}
\textheight 21.8cm \textwidth 15.cm \topmargin 0.cm \oddsidemargin
0.cm \evensidemargin 0.cm
\parindent=10pt
\itemsep=0pt
\parskip=0pt
\baselineskip=0pt
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[Frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{bm}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
%\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
%\usepackage[ruled,vlined,french,titlenumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
%\usepackage[boxed]{algorithm}
%\usepackage[]{algorithm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[francais]{minitoc}
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{french}
....
```

Any idea please?

Thank you

Comment: What input code produces this?

Comment: Off-topic: don't specify `pdftex` to `graphicx`. Better to use `geometry` and `parskip`. Setting `\baselineskip` to zero will look horrible so only do this if it is an institutional requirement. (Those always look horrible so it can't be helped.) Recommend using UTF8 encoding for your files, especially if writing French. None of these options seem to do anything: `onehalfspacing,headrules,tools`. Consider `xcolor` rather than `color`. You do not need `\selectlanguage` for the main language. Always post complete but minimal examples people can try to compile to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably you have

```
\documentclass[French]{<class>}
```

or

```
\documentclass[Frenchb]{<class>}
```

or

```
\usepackage[French]{babel}
```

or

```
\usepackage[Frenchb]{babel}
```

None of these are correct.

What you need is

```
\documentclass[frenchb]{<class>}
```

or

```
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
```

or

```
\documentclass[french]{<class>}
```

or

```
\usepackage[french]{babel}
```

Comment: I modify it to \usepackage[French]{babel} but the same problem

Comment: @CyrineEzzahra I suggested that was the problem. OK. Actually the problem is `Frenchb`. But the solution is the same either way and I was guessing before you posted code. Use `frenchb` or `french`. Either will work just fine.

Comment: @CyrineEzzahra The problem isn't the `b` or not. The problem is the `F`. You want `f` with or without the `b`.

Comment: It's a problem with Windows that has a case insensitive file system, so asking for `Frenchb.ldf` is the same as asking for `fReNCh.LdF`. People take bad habits and, when switching to a real OS, they get into trouble.

Comment: @egreg I know what causes it. But OS X is worse - or used to be - since it is half case-sensitive and half case-insensitive. Yet I would count it as a real OS. Just a flawed one. (Well, they're all flawed. Even the non-real ones are flawed in non-real-OS ways.)